# Clarification How CRF(Conditional random Field) works using examples

Tags: machine-learning

I read different documents how CRF(conditional random field) works but all the papers puts the formula only. Is there any one who can send me a paper that describes about CRF with examples like if we have a sentence

"Mr.Smith was born in New York. He has been working for the last 20 years in Microsoft company."

if the above sentence is given as an input to train, how does the Model works during the training taking in to consideration for the formula for CRF?
Smith is tagged as "PER" New York is as "LOC" Microsoft Company as "ORG".
Moges.A

Comment: @bayer which thing u don't understand? Moges want to know how the algorith works if above example is given as input. Just the user want to know the real working

Comment: [Here](http://blog.echen.me/2012/01/03/introduction-to-conditional-random-fields/) is a great layman explanation of CRFs.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a [link](http://cs.nyu.edu/~dsontag/courses/pgm12/slides/lecture3.pdf) to a set of slides made by Shasha Rush, a PhD student who is currently working on NLP at Google. One of the reasons I really like the slides is because they contain concrete examples and walk you through executions of important algorithms.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden I seem to have added a period at the end of the linked URL. You should be able to access the slides now.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a paper, but there is available whole online free course on [probabilistic graphical models](https://www.coursera.org/pgm/auth/welcome) -- CRF is one of them.
It is very definitive and you'll get an intuitive level of understanding after completing it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think somebody will write such tutorial. You can check HMM tutorial which is easier to understand and can be explained by example. The problem with CRF is that it is global optimization with many dependencies, so it is very hard to show step by step how we optimize parameters and how we predict labels. But the idea is very simple - maximization of dependency(clique) graph using sparsity...